# Separate two columns from one file to two separate files in for loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

An input file **list_c**, looks like:

```
00000981.ffid   00000982.ffid
00000982.ffid   00000983.ffid
00000983.ffid   00000984.ffid
00000984.ffid   00000985.ffid
00000985.ffid   00000986.ffid
00000986.ffid   00000987.ffid
00000987.ffid   00000988.ffid
00000988.ffid   00000989.ffid
00000989.ffid   00000990.ffid
00000990.ffid   00000991.ffid
00000991.ffid   00000992.ffid
00000992.ffid   00000993.ffid
00000993.ffid   00000994.ffid
00000994.ffid   00000995.ffid
00000995.ffid   00000996.ffid
00000996.ffid   00000997.ffid
00000997.ffid   00000998.ffid
00000998.ffid   00000999.ffid
00000999.ffid   00001000.ffid
00001000.ffid   00001001.ffid
00001001.ffid   00001002.ffid
00001002.ffid   00001003.ffid
00001003.ffid   00001004.ffid
00001004.ffid   00001005.ffid
00001005.ffid   00001006.ffid
00001006.ffid   00001007.ffid
00001007.ffid
```

I want to separate the two columns into two separate variables and use them in a loop for generating two output files.

I am using this code :

```
for filename in $(cat /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/list_c)
do 
    echo "$filename" | awk '{print $1}' >> /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/C_ffid
    echo "$filename" | awk '{print $2}' >> /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/N_ffid
done
```

But what I get is **C_ffid**:

```
00000981.ffid
00000982.ffid
00000982.ffid
00000983.ffid
00000983.ffid
00000984.ffid
00000984.ffid
00000985.ffid
00000985.ffid
00000986.ffid
00000986.ffid
00000987.ffid
00000987.ffid
00000988.ffid
00000988.ffid
00000989.ffid
00000989.ffid
00000990.ffid
00000990.ffid
00000991.ffid
00000991.ffid
00000992.ffid
00000992.ffid
00000993.ffid
00000993.ffid
00000994.ffid
00000994.ffid
00000995.ffid
00000995.ffid
00000996.ffid
00000996.ffid
00000997.ffid
00000997.ffid
00000998.ffid
00000998.ffid
00000999.ffid
00000999.ffid
00001000.ffid
00001000.ffid
00001001.ffid
00001001.ffid
00001002.ffid
00001002.ffid
00001003.ffid
00001003.ffid
00001004.ffid
00001004.ffid
00001005.ffid
00001005.ffid
00001006.ffid
00001006.ffid
00001007.ffid
00001007.ffid
```

Whereas the other file **N_ffid** is blank.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write column 1 and column 2 to separate files:

```
awk '{print $1>"/path/to/C_ffid"; print $2>"/path/to/N_ffid"}' list_c
```

#### How it works

- `print $1>"/path/to/C_ffid"`

  This command writes the first column to file `/path/to/C_ffid`.
- `print $2>"/path/to/N_ffid"`

  This command writes the second column to file `/path/to/N_ffid`.

#### Sample output

For your input file, the following two output files are created:

```
$ cat C_ffid 
00000981.ffid
00000982.ffid
00000983.ffid
00000984.ffid
00000985.ffid
00000986.ffid
00000987.ffid
00000988.ffid
00000989.ffid
00000990.ffid
00000991.ffid
00000992.ffid
00000993.ffid
00000994.ffid
00000995.ffid
00000996.ffid
00000997.ffid
00000998.ffid
00000999.ffid
00001000.ffid
00001001.ffid
00001002.ffid
00001003.ffid
00001004.ffid
00001005.ffid
00001006.ffid
00001007.ffid
```

And:

```
$ cat N_ffid 
00000982.ffid
00000983.ffid
00000984.ffid
00000985.ffid
00000986.ffid
00000987.ffid
00000988.ffid
00000989.ffid
00000990.ffid
00000991.ffid
00000992.ffid
00000993.ffid
00000994.ffid
00000995.ffid
00000996.ffid
00000997.ffid
00000998.ffid
00000999.ffid
00001000.ffid
00001001.ffid
00001002.ffid
00001003.ffid
00001004.ffid
00001005.ffid
00001006.ffid
00001007.ffid
```

#### Looping and processing in shell

```
while read one two
do
   echo "$one">>C_ffid
   echo "$two">>N_ffid
   echo "Processing $one and $two"
done <list_c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, it generates two files , but when I use it in a loop it as I mentioned in my code , it creates them the same number of times the loop is iterated that is equal to the number of files in the list.

Comment: @AbhishakeYadav This code was intended to completely replace and eliminate that loop.  You can certainly do further processing on `C_ffid` and `N_ffid` if you want afterward.

Comment: @AbhishakeYadav If you prefer it, I just added some code that allows looping and processing at the same time.

Comment: Thanks John ,  I want to run various processes/ commands in the same loop using variables which are generated from the two columns of the list_c , but I have no idea how to define two different  variables from two columns   of the same file  when the loop runs lines by line can you please help.

Comment: Can I define this while inside my for loop?

Comment: Please clarify: define what inside what loop?

Comment: _"I have no idea how to define two different variables from two columns of the same file "_  The looping code does just that.  The first column is assigned to variable `one` and the second to variable `two`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is, You are using the awk to print the column1 and column2. The awk command works with space as a separator for the column separating. In your file have the more than one space in between the two columns. So, only you get the second file as blank. If you want it in awk, change your file, with single space between the two columns and execute. It also will work.

Otherwise,

You can use the cut command to delimit that and store it into the variable In the starting and you can use those variables in the loop.

Assume in between both columns have the tab. The below code will do what you expect. The var1 variable contains the first column values and var2 variable contains the seconds column values.

```
var1=`cut -d'     ' -f1 list_c`
var2=`cut -d'     ' -f2 list_c`

for filename in $var1
do 
    echo "$filename" >>C_ffid
done 

for filename in $var2
do 
    echo "$filename" >>C_ffid1
done
```

But In any way make sure about the delimiter for separating in cut command or awk command.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX shell script, conceptually similar to the OP's code, *sans* **awk**:

```
cd /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/
while read a b ; do  
    echo "$a" >> C_ffid
    echo "$b" >> N_ffid
done < list_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **cut**, assuming *list_c_ is *tab* separated:

```
cd /d/home/adira0151/Desktop/tmp/
cut -f 1 < list_c > C_ffid
cut -f 2 < list_c > N_ffid
```

If *space* separated, this would work:

```
tr -s ' ' '\t' < list_c | cut -f 1 > C_ffid
tr -s ' ' '\t' < list_c | cut -f 2 > N_ffid
```

Note, running over *one* input file *twice* is inefficient, these would benefit from using a parallel input util like **[pee](https://serverfault.com/questions/96245/linux-debian-what-does-pee-in-moreutils-do)**, e.g.:

```
tr -s ' ' '\t' < list_c | pee "cut -f 1 > C_ffid" "cut -f 2 > N_ffid"
```

Or, if tab separated:

```
pee "cut -f 1 > C_ffid" "cut -f 2 > N_ffid" < list_c
```